# C++0x function<>, bind and members

Tags: c++11, bind, functional-programming, pointer-to-member

I tried to follow [Bjarne Stroustups](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-function) explanation of the `function` template. I specifically played with the interchangability of *c-function-pointers*, *functors*, *lambdas* and *member-function-pointers*

Given the defintions:

```
struct IntDiv { // functor
  float operator()(int x, int y) const
    { return ((float)x)/y; }
};

// function pointer
float cfunc(int x, int y) { return (float)x+y; }

struct X { // member function
  float mem(int x, int y) const { return ...; }
};
using namespace placeholders; // _1, _2, ...
```

I want to assign to `function<float(int,int)>` everything possible:

```
int main() {
  // declare function object
  function<float (int x, int y)> f;
  //== functor ==
  f = IntDiv{};  // OK
  //== lambda ==
  f = [](int x,int y)->float { return ((float)y)/x; }; // OK
  //== funcp ==
  f = &cfunc; // OK

  // derived from bjarnes faq:
  function<float(X*,int,int)> g; // extra argument 'this'
  g = &X::mem; // set to memer function      
  X x{}; // member function calls need a 'this'
  cout << g(&x, 7,8); // x->mem(7,8), OK.

  //== member function ==
  f = bind(g, &x,_2,_3); // ERROR
}
```

And the last line gives a typical unreadable compiler-template-error. *sigh*.

I want to bind `f` to an existing `x` instances member function, so that only the signature `float(int,int)` is left.

**What should be the line instead of**

```
f = bind(g, &x,_2,_3);
```

**...or where else is the error?**

---

Background:

Here comes Bjarnes example for using `bind` and `function` with a member function:

```
struct X {
    int foo(int);
};
function<int (X*, int)> f;
f = &X::foo;        // pointer to member
X x;
int v = f(&x, 5);   // call X::foo() for x with 5
function<int (int)> ff = std::bind(f,&x,_1)
```

I *thought* `bind` is used this way: The un-assigned places get `placeholders`, the rest is filled in the `bind`. Should `_1` nut get `this`, then`? And therefore the last line be:

```
function<int (int)> ff = std::bind(f,&x,_2)
```

---

**On Howards suggestion** below I tried it :-) [image: order of args in bind]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
f = bind(g, &x,_1,_2); // OK
```

The placeholders refer to the argument positions in the returned bind object.  The don't index `g`'s parameters.

Comment: Oh, amazing I missed that until now. I think I need to make drawing for that, for when I need to explain it myself.

Comment: If you figure out how to publish that drawing back here that would be great! I'm sure it would help a lot of people! :-)